# Check if current user undoing/redoing?

Tags: hooks, undo

Is there a way so that the Emacs are able to tell if the current user is undoing/redoing in the current buffer?

Here is the task I want to accomplish, I have add a hook to `after-change-function`, it all works out great exclusive of when I hit undo/redo this hook get called too. And this is what I want to avoid... Is there other way to get around this issue?

Comment: Welcome.  Can you give an example of what you are trying to use this for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `undo-in-progress`

```
Documentation:
Non-nil while performing an undo.
Some change-hooks test this variable to do something different.
```

Bearing in mind that "redoing" is really still "undoing" in Emacs, this ought to cover all cases.

Comment: @Jen-ChiehShen : please upvote and accept the answer if it resolves the problem. Thanks!